# Update command can't find the correct value of the control

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview, findcontrol, updatecommand

I have created a table in side the edititemtamlate of grid view.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <%--    <asp:Panel ID="pnltable" runat="server">--%>
<table border="1px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" >
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T1" runat="server" ID="Label111"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T2" runat="server" ID="Label112"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T3" runat="server" ID="Label113"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T4" runat="server" ID="Label114"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T5" runat="server" ID="Label115"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T6" runat="server" ID="Label116"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T7" runat="server" ID="Label117"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T8" runat="server" ID="Label118"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T9" runat="server" ID="Label119"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="T10" runat="server" ID="Label1110"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox11" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox12" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox13" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox14" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox15" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox16" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox17" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox18" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox19" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox20" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
    <%--</asp:Panel>--%>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

When user clicks on the edit button this table shows with the value from the tables..
For this I write the code in editcommand like this which work perfectly.

```
Guid SubscriptionId = (Guid)Subscriptions.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value;
var s = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPlanning.GetSingleSubVersionTrueFalse(SubscriptionId);
CheckBox d11 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox11");
CheckBox d12 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox12");
CheckBox d13 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox13");
CheckBox d14 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox14");
CheckBox d15 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox15");
CheckBox d16 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox16");
CheckBox d17 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox17");
CheckBox d18 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox18");
CheckBox d19 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox19");
CheckBox d20 = (CheckBox)Subscriptions.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox20");

    if (d11 != null){
        d11.Checked = s.T1.Value;
    }
    if (d12 != null){
        d12.Checked = s.T2.Value;
    }
    if (d13 != null){
        d13.Checked = s.T3.Value;
    }
    if (d14 != null){
        d14.Checked = s.T4.Value;
    }
    if (d15 != null){
        d15.Checked = s.T5.Value;
    }
    if (d16 != null){
        d16.Checked = s.T6.Value;
    }
    if (d17 != null){
        d17.Checked = s.T7.Value;
    }
    if (d18 != null){
        d18.Checked = s.T8.Value;
    }
    if (d19 != null) {
        d19.Checked = s.T9.Value;
    }
    if (d20 != null){
        d20.Checked = s.T10.Value;
    }
```

Now in the update command when i change the checkbox value and try to update it like in this code in update command

```
CheckBox c1 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox11"));
CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("CheckBox12"));
CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox13"));
CheckBox c4 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox14"));
CheckBox c5 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox15"));
CheckBox c6 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox16"));
CheckBox c7 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox17"));
CheckBox c8 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox18"));
CheckBox c9 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox19"));
CheckBox c10 = (CheckBox)(Subscriptions.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox20"));

if (c1 != null && c2 != null && c3 != null && c4 != null && c5 != null && c6 != null && c7 != null && c8 != null && c9 != null && c10 != null)
{
    m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPlanning.UpdateSubVersionTrueFalseForUpdate(subscriptionID, c1.Checked, c2.Checked, c3.Checked, c4.Checked, c5.Checked, c6.Checked, c7.Checked, c8.Checked, c9.Checked, c10.Checked);
}
```

But here it is not giving any error but when I debug the code I show that,
in the checkbox controls c1 to c10 in update command it always gets value
`Checked = false`

even if i check the checkbox.

So that it updates in a wrong way.

Can any tell me where I am wrong..?

Comment: Set **checkBox** `AutoPostBack="False"` and see whether it works

Comment: @satindersingh Its still not working..

Comment: what values are for T1,T2,T3..., IS it `True/False O/1`

Comment: T1 to T10 are all true by default for all users..

Comment: @ Hiral Bavisi: T1,T2,T3.. are all labels you were placed under EditTemplate along with CheckBox, am i right, so on edit button click what you trying to achieve am not clear about it,

Comment: @satindersingh its shows correct values when I click on edit but after changing some check box value when I update the grid view it puts all T1 to T10 false because in the find control,it gets false for all check box and update the database with this incorrect value..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21763/discussion-between-satinder-singh-and-hiral-bavisi)

Comment: @satindersingh Yes..they are just labels..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is small example what i tried

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
       bindgv();
  }
}

public void bindgv()
{
  SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from mytable", Con);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  dap.Fill(ds);
  GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
  CheckBox c1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox1");
  CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox2");
  CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBox3");
  Label lblid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblid");
  updateMethod(lblid.Text, c1.Checked, c2.Checked, c3.Checked);

}

public void updateMethod(string id, bool c1, bool c2, bool c3)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myCon))
  {
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update mytable set c1= @c1value , c2=@c2value, c3= @c3value where id=@id", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1value", c1);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2value", c2);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3value", c3);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bindgv();
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  bindgv();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
  bindgv();
}
```

**HTML MarkUp**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="checkbox">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>   
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c1") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c2") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c3") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>  
     <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("c1") %>' /></td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("c2") %>' /></td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("c3") %>' /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
   <table>
    <tr>   
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c1") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c2") %>'></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c3") %>'></asp:Label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>  
    <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("c1") %>' /></td>
    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("c2") %>' /></td>
    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("c3") %>' /></td>
  </tr>
   </table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**ScreenShot:**

[image: ScreenShot]